# Github code retrieval returns sha hash instead of actual code

Tags: github

I'm uploading my code to github, but when I navigate to it in the web browser I can't actually read the code unless I click on "view raw" or "download."

If I make code changes and upload them:

```
git add *
git commit -m "test"
Git push origin master
```

and then fetch them again:

```
git fetch --all
git reset --hard master
```

My code is replaced with this:

```
version https://git-lfs.github.com/spec/v1
oid sha256:01fb22a63967e11c50ac23ecb33144bebc7d2a9f011e19cdd0681cd2873aff02
size 12550
```

Any idea whats going on or how to fix it?

Answer (score 0):

I suggest you delete your repo on your GitHub, and do it all over again using this workflow.

1 Add + commit, which you did correct:

```
git add *

git commit -m "test"
```

2 Create a remote branch:

```
git push origin Remote-Branch-Name
```

3 Push to remote branch:

```
git push -u origin Remote-Branch-Name
```

This should upload you code as actual code, and not SHA.

Comment: When I do that i get fatal: invalid refspec. Don't I need to init?

Comment: After which command do you get this error?

Comment: Yes, you do need to 'git init'. I assumed you already took care of that step.